# PHP variable scope - How to share variable between two functions without using arguments?

Tags: php, global-variables, scope

I have a small problem in a script I can't solve on my own. Having studied the PHP documentation regarding variable scope, I am not sure if this is even possible.

Take the following example:

```
function my_funct_a() {
    // Do stuff
    return $a;
}

function my_funct_b() {
    // Do other stuff
    return $a + $b;
}
```

You see, the problem is that in `my_funct_b`, `$a` is not available because it was declared (and is returned) in `my_funct_a`.

Normally I would pass this variable as an argument, but this is not possible at this point due to some kind of framework limitation.

So I tried to do it like this:

```
function my_funct_a() {
    // Do stuff
    global $a;
    return $a;
}

function my_funct_b() {
    // Do other stuff
    global $a;
    return $a + $b;
}
```

This also didn't work, I think because `global` works 'the other way around'. Instead of declaring a variable as global inside a function to be available outside the function, it has to be declared as global outside the function to be available inside the function.

The Problem is that the value of `$a` is created in `my_funct_a`, so I can't global it before the value is known.
Because of that, I tried to do it like this:

```
// global variable, but no value assigned yet
global $a

function my_funct_a() {
   // Do stuff
   global $a;
   $a = 1; 
   return $a;
}

function my_funct_b() {
   // Do other stuff
   global $a;
   return $a + $b;
}
```

This also didn't work. Why? Is it even possible without passing the variable as an argument?

Comment: Is this a class code?

Comment: In `my_funct_b()`, how do you get `$b`? Same question for `my_funct_a()` btw.

Comment: @DonCallisto No,procedural PHP is used in that project.

Comment: @Jack `$a` is a dynamic value created inside that function, `$b` is a string using that dynamic value. I am afraid I have to to it using the two functions

Comment: Your understanding of how `global` works is wrong. You declare it _inside_ the function, and it allows that function to access the global variable with that name. Your second try should have worked.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/OSuyaZ

Answer (score 1):

The best way to encapsulate data and functionality is a class:

```
class Foo {

    protected $val = 1;

    public function inc() {
        return $this->val += 1;
    }

    public function dec() {
        return $this->val -= 1;
    }

}
```

I'm showing this because it should be used in favour of global variables attempt.

However, this should work:

```
$val = 1;

function inc() {
    global $val;
    return $val += 1;
}


function dec() {
    global $val;
    return $val -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of `$a` and it can only be created with `my_funct_a()`, then add this as a dependency inside `my_funct_b()`:

```
function my_funct_b() 
{
    $a = my_funct_a();
    // Do other stuff

    return $a + $b;
}
```

Comment: Seems the best solution to me, but maybe - as you said before edit - I din't get the real issue ...

Answer (score 0):

You put the `global` declaration inside the function. That causes uses of the variable within that function to refer to a global variable, not a local one. And if two functions both access the same global variable, they'll see the same values.

```
function my_funct_a() {
    global $a;
    $a = 10;
    return $a;
}

function my_funct_b() {
    $b = 5;
    global $a;
    return $a + $b;
}

echo my_funct_a() . "\n";
echo my_funct_b();
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/OSuyaZ)

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
```

> The above script will output 3. By declaring $a and $b global within
>   the function, all references to either variable will refer to the
>   global version.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: This isn't what OP's asking for

Comment: This is exactly was he is asking about. He shouldn't use 'global' word when declaring global variable (outside functions), and thats it.